# ArangoDB restore from backup, including User Passwords

Tags: collections, passwords, restore, arangodb

I have an instance of ArangoDB 1.4 I need to restore from backup. I used arangodump to back up the database and I'm restoring with arangorestore. All the data seems to restore properly except for the users passwords in the _users collection. It creates a property on the user document called password that contains an encrypted string. Is there a way to make it restore the user passwords?

UPDATE: On second look everything is importing wrong. documents are importing with a data property that contains all the data for the document that was imported. This obviously will not work. How can I get this data to import properly?

UPDATE 2: it looks like the import process is probably working fine, but the dump is what got strange. It dumped each document with a wrapper document like this:

```
{"type":2300,"key":"540727924","rev":"540727924","data":
    {"_key":"540727924","_rev":"540727924","type":"group"}
}
```

Not sure what the "type,key,rev,data" wrapper document is for, but appears to be goofing up the restore process. Worst case scenario I will write a script that imports these documents without the wrapper. But it would be great if there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords are stored in ArangoDB as salted hash values. The original passwords are not stored and cannot be recovered from the hash value. 
This is done for security reasons and is common practice elsewhere, too. 
As ArangoDB does not use plain-text passwords I don't think this will cause any problems when re-importing data.

As far as I can see, the dump and restore operations are correct. Dumping data intentionally wraps all documents' data into a `data` attribute. This is because dumping may not only dump documents from the collections but may also dump removal operations (which then will be re-applied by a restore operation). The `type` attribute indicates what type of data you're looking at, with `2300` being a regular document (and `2301` being an edge and `2302` being a removal operation).

The data produced by arangodump can be reimported using arangorestore and does not need to be converted. Writing your own scripts for that is not necessary from my point of view.

One thing that comes to my mind regarding passwords after a restore is that ArangoDB keeps some password data in a cache, and that this cache may not be updated automatically by a restore operation.

To check if this is the case and leads to the problem you're facing, can you try stopping and re-starting the server after the restore? If authentication works ok after that but not before, there might be an issue with the password cache.

Apart from that, what kind of problem are you actually experiencing when using the data produced by arangodump in an arangorestore operation? It is not quite clear from the post what is going wrong.

Comment: What I ended up doing was upgrading to the newest version of ArangoDB, using RegEx formulas to remove the "wrapper" documents, and then manually imported the json into each collection. Not sure why but when I used ArangoRestore it would restore the "wrapper" documents, which is obviously not what I wanted.

Comment: Strange. I just dumped the _users collection from an ArangoDB 1.4 using 1.4's `arangodump` and imported it into an ArangoDB 2.2 using 2.2's `arangorestore`. No problems there, and also the documents all look ok, without wrapper attributes around them. Have you used `arangoimp` to re-import the documents? That will create wrapper attributes, but `arangorestore` shouldn't.